# xacro command not found

Tags: ros, srdf, ros-indigo, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a xacro command to generate the latest `baxter.srdf` file to use with Moveit config.  I found the command in a readme file in the `baxter_moveit_config` folder.  It has been modified to give the paths to the files since it was having trouble finding them:

```
xacro --inorder ~/ros_ws/src/moveit_robots/baxter/baxter_moveit_config/config/baxter.srdf.xacro left_electric_gripper:=true right_electric_gripper:=true left_tip_name:=left_gripper right_tip_name:=right_gripper >> ~/ros_ws/src/moveit_robots/baxter/baxter_moveit_config/config/baxter.srdf
```

I keep getting:

```
xacro:  command not found
```

I have sourced everything properly:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

I even ran a `catkin_make` and tried it again.  When I run `rospack find xacro` it returns the location of it.  I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04 with Ros Indigo.

`printenv | grep` ROS output:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/baxter/ros_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309683/xacro-command-not-found/) by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-30**:
How have you installed ROS? The xacro binary should be located at `/opt/ros/<version>/bin/xacro` You can install it manually with `sudo apt-get install ros-<version>-xacro`

**Comment by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on 2018-11-30**:
It is installed and I have ran it many times.  I can try manually installing the xacro package again to see if that fixes it though.  Here is were rospack find says it is:
/opt/ros/indigo/share/xacro

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-30**:
Can you add the output of the linux command `printenv | grep ROS` to your question, so we can check your environment.

**Comment by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on 2018-11-30**:
I ran the install and the rospack find came back with the same location.  I get the same command not found message when I run the xacro command.

**Comment by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on 2018-11-30**:
printenv |  grep ROS output:
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/baxter/ros_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe `xacro` is put on the regular `PATH` on Trusty/Indigo. That is only in Kinetic (and Jade probably). You should probably use `rosrun xacro xacro ..`.

---

Note: the readme you refer to (probably [this one](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_robots/blob/d3eaf514c31d6f902ac4e1ac5a9ff61c852eee05/baxter/baxter_moveit_config/README.md)) is the readme for Kinetic. The Indigo one ([this one](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_robots/blob/2a4bbe3d9f058c7f7736eb8bd8c5b5e857865671/baxter/baxter_moveit_config/README.md)) does not contain any instructions to generate an `.srdf`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mewescott](https://answers.ros.org/users/31649/mewescott/) on 2018-12-01**:
If that is the case then I somehow loaded the incorrect version.  Do I need to switch it?  I want to do a project with Flexbe and I need to run MoveIt configuration wizard to setup the points. Can I run the Kinetic package on an Indigo ROS setup?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-02**:
You'd have to ask the maintainers of that package whether that is possible.